# local wpf binding How should be done?

Tags: wpf, binding, local

guys I wanna use my own "usercontrol" in the main window, but i have problem with this line `<local:texttoolbar x:Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top">`

The name of project is wpfin8 so i put it in the line with namespace

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfin8">
```

main user control xaml code looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextEditor.TextEditorToolbar"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
```

and the name is texttoolbar.xaml

The piece of mainwindow code is

```
<Window x:Class="wpfin8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfin8">
```

```
    <Menu x:Name="menu"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Menu>
    <local:texttoolbar x:Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar>
            <Button >open
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="10,0,0,0">
                save
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </local:texttoolbar>
```

I think i did everything properly and it dont want work and it still underlined with this "the name texttoolbar does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:wpfin8" " , I've also tried with the "TextEditorToolbar" , "TextEditor"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U Need to add assembly name also to your UserControl namespace used in MainWindow

like->

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfin8;assembly=wpfin8"
```

assembly name may be different .. U can check that  in your UserControl Properties named under AssemblyNamespace..

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: I check it in property pages of wpfin8, and assembly name is wpfin8 also, but the error is still the same " The name "texttoolbar" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:wpfin8;assembly=wpfin8".  You said also about user control properties but i cant find the assemblynamespace there

Comment: Have You included your user control as a project in the main project..??

Comment: First include your UserControl project inside the main project and than go to refrence folder in the main project and right click it to add reference and add your project in the main project reference..than it will work fine.

Comment: I make it one more time and now its works, I'm not sure what was the problem, thx for the advices it shows me what is important in this process

Comment: So can you mark it as an Answer so that it will be helpful for others too.. :)